# Close PageRender after starting activity in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android-activity, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In the [Forms2Native](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Forms2Native)'s Android example, the `MyThirdPageRenderer` starts a new activity `MyThirdActivity`. However, when going back from `MyThirdActivity`, we get a blank page and we need to push the go back button one more time to back to the main page. How do we kill that blank page automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like someone ran into the exact same issue as you and already posted a bug report. But within the bug report they mentioned that it is an issue with that particular sample and not an issue with Xamarin Forms itself. Check it out here, hope that helps:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=23983